# How can I recode matchup values in R that are not consistent throughout the dataset?

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

I have a dataset containing team (roster_id), who that team played (matchup_id), how many points the team (roster_id) scored, which week it occurred (Week), and what season the matchup occurred (Season).

The roster_id values are all the individual team names, but the matchup_id values are numerical (1-6).

Meaning: within the same Week, if two teams have the same matchup_id that means they played each other. I am trying to recode the matchup values to the roster_id they played that week, but they change combinations on a week to week basis.

Here's what the first two weeks of the dataset look like:

```
structure(list(roster_id = c("Benzo", "Malik", "Tyco", "Los", 
"JG", "Dally", "Pini", "Trum", "Toney", "Antbo", "Benzo", "Malik", 
"Tyco", "Los", "JG", "Dally", "Pini", "Trum", "Toney", "Antbo"
), matchup_id = c("1", "3", "3", "5", "5", "1", "4", "2", "4", 
"2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "4", "1", "5", "2", "3", "1"), points = c(232.03, 
198.48, 189.78, 171.18, 198.23, 202.81, 167.23, 208.73, 197.5, 
206.51, 165.83, 244.37, 253.5, 238.42, 196.22, 189.7, 151.57, 
223.55, 189.98, 144.26), Week = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Season = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

For example: In Week 1, Benzo and Dally both have matchup_id = 1 (meaning they played each other that week). But in Week 2, Dally and Antbo both have matchup_id = 1 (since they played each other in Week 2. This same process repeats every week of every season.

**How can I recode these matchup_id values to be named for who they actually played that week? Rather than them being numbers. Thanks in advance.**

I have tried various dplyr functions to recode the data, but have not been successful. I could do it all by hand in Excel, but the API brings in the data directly from the website so I'd have to export to Excel and reload the dataset back into R.. hoping for a more efficient approach to this.

EDIT: I tried

```
  group_by(Week, matchup_id) %>%
  mutate(matchup_id = list(roster_id)) %>%
  unnest_longer(matchup_id) %>%
  filter(roster_id != matchup_id)
```

but it doesn't format it correctly. Here's what the dataset looks like when I apply it to the entire dataset.

```
structure(list(roster_id = c("Benzo", "Benzo", "Benzo", "Benzo", 
"Malik", "Malik", "Malik", "Malik", "Malik", "Tyco", "Tyco", 
"Tyco", "Tyco", "Los", "Los", "Los", "Los", "Los", "JG", "JG", 
"JG", "JG", "Dally", "Dally"), matchup_id = c("Dally", "Dally", 
"Los", "Toney", "Tyco", "Tyco", "Trum", "Benzo", "Dally", "Malik", 
"Trum", "Benzo", "Dally", "JG", "JG", "Antbo", "Malik", "Pini", 
"Los", "Antbo", "Malik", "Pini", "Benzo", "Benzo"), points = c(232.03, 
232.03, 232.03, 232.03, 198.48, 198.48, 198.48, 198.48, 198.48, 
189.78, 189.78, 189.78, 189.78, 171.18, 171.18, 171.18, 171.18, 
171.18, 198.23, 198.23, 198.23, 198.23, 202.81, 202.81), Week = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), Season = c("2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = structure(list(
    Week = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
    ), matchup_id = c("Antbo", "Benzo", "Dally", "JG", "Los", 
    "Malik", "Pini", "Toney", "Trum", "Tyco"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(16L, 20L), c(8L, 12L, 23L, 24L), c(1L, 2L, 9L, 13L), 
        14:15, c(3L, 19L), c(10L, 17L, 21L), c(18L, 22L), 4L, 
        c(7L, 11L), 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there are a few ways to tackle this problem; here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(roster_id = c("Benzo", "Malik", "Tyco", "Los", 
                                   "JG", "Dally", "Pini", "Trum", "Toney", "Antbo", "Benzo", "Malik", 
                                   "Tyco", "Los", "JG", "Dally", "Pini", "Trum", "Toney", "Antbo"), 
                     matchup_id = c("1", "3", "3", "5", "5", "1", "4", "2", "4", 
                                    "2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "4", "1", "5", "2", "3", "1"), 
                     points = c(232.03, 
                                198.48, 189.78, 171.18, 198.23, 202.81, 167.23, 208.73, 197.5, 
                                206.51, 165.83, 244.37, 253.5, 238.42, 196.22, 189.7, 151.57, 
                                223.55, 189.98, 144.26), 
                     Week = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                              1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                     Season = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)),
                row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  group_by(Week, matchup_id) %>%
  mutate(matchup_id = list(roster_id)) %>%
  unnest_longer(matchup_id) %>%
  filter(roster_id != matchup_id)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#> # Groups:   Week, matchup_id [20]
#>    roster_id matchup_id points  Week Season
#>    <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Benzo     Dally        232.     1   2020
#>  2 Malik     Tyco         198.     1   2020
#>  3 Tyco      Malik        190.     1   2020
#>  4 Los       JG           171.     1   2020
#>  5 JG        Los          198.     1   2020
#>  6 Dally     Benzo        203.     1   2020
#>  7 Pini      Toney        167.     1   2020
#>  8 Trum      Antbo        209.     1   2020
#>  9 Toney     Pini         198.     1   2020
#> 10 Antbo     Trum         207.     1   2020
#> 11 Benzo     Trum         166.     2   2020
#> 12 Malik     Toney        244.     2   2020
#> 13 Tyco      JG           254.     2   2020
#> 14 Los       Pini         238.     2   2020
#> 15 JG        Tyco         196.     2   2020
#> 16 Dally     Antbo        190.     2   2020
#> 17 Pini      Los          152.     2   2020
#> 18 Trum      Benzo        224.     2   2020
#> 19 Toney     Malik        190.     2   2020
#> 20 Antbo     Dally        144.     2   2020
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I edited my original question with some another issue I encountered when using this solution. @jarod_mamrot

Comment: Maybe your data were already grouped? If you `ungroup()` them, then try my code (i.e. `df %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(Week, matchup_id) %>% etc`) does it work @jgsnow?

Comment: No luck.. going to continue playing with it and research other potential methods as well.